# hr tag responsive based on screen size

Tags: html, css, tags

i used hr tag. i give 30% width to hr tag. as i zoom my screen, width of hr tag is remain same .and when i small my screen width remain same.

[image: image shows when my screen size full 1005]
but  i want responsive  width based on page size . how can i do ??
when i zoom in i want width of hr tag also small.
i attached 2 image. first is screen size is 100% and second one is screen size is 50%
my html is:

```
        `<div class="home-page-image">
        <img src={{homePageImage}}/>
        <header>
        <h3>Refer & Earn</h3>
        <hr width="31%">
        <p>Introduce a friend and get rewarded</p>
        </header>
        </div>`
```

and scss is

```
 home-page-image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    filter: opacity(50%);
  }
  header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    h3 {
      font-size: 36px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: -8px;
    }
    hr {
      border-style: inset;
      margin-top: 19px;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
      width: 31%;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: #5D5C5D;
      font-style: normal;
    }
  }
}`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a bit more code? Looks like your `hr` tag is nested as a child inside another element with a specified width. This means that giving it a width of 30% will produce a width relative to said parent container instead of the screen width.

If you need a quick-fix, you can use `30vw`, which can give you the desired effect, but I wouldn't advise that. 
You need to make sure your code is structured properly to avoid any unnecessary surprises in the future.

Comment: 30vw is also not working . i will post code . give me 2 minutes

Comment: The code samples you gave worked. The `hr` tag was responsive.

Comment: but why it not changes width when my screen size is 50%

Comment: Is your site live? I could take a look at the code and assist you in debugging the problem.